# Kafka Streams: group messages up to an aggregated field sum value treshold or a time frame

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

How to emit a message in a topic, out of incoming messages from another topic, with respect to the following rules?

1. Events are grouped by keys values.
2. Each emitted event is an aggregation of a set of incoming events, in their order, by the first that complies to one of the following conditions:

- a time frame has passed (let's say events within 5 minutes per key) from the last aggregated set (in event timestamps, not in real time);
- an aggregated event field value by summing the values of that field, also per key, has passed a threshold (let's say 100).

Comment: Sounds like a case for a custom `Processor`.